# How do I communicate between parent and child processes using signals and shared memory?

Tags: c, operating-system, signals, shared-memory

I am trying to write a program to input data from a user to parent. Then  send that data to child.Finally, child performs some action on the data and sends back to parent where it is printed. The data should be stored in shared memory only and communication to be done using signals.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#define SHM_KEY 0x1234

void sigfun(int sig) //signal handler
{
 printf("You have presses Ctrl-C, please press again to exit\n");
 signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
}
int main()
{
  int shmid;
  char * shmp;
  shmid=shmget(SHM_KEY, 100, 0644|IPC_CREAT);
  if(shmid==-1)
  {
  perror("Shared Memory error: ");
  exit(-1);
  }
  printf("100 bytes of shared memory segment created and its ID is: %d\n",shmid);
  shmp=shmat(shmid,NULL,0);
  if(shmp==NULL)
  {
  perror("shmat() error: ");
  exit(-1);
  }
  printf("\nSegment attached to process:%d and its address is:%p\n",getpid(),shmp);

 signal(SIGINT, sigfun);
 while (1)
 {
 printf("Hello world, ......\n");
 sleep(1);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the title should be taken as the question, then I feel this question is a bit broad.

Comment: how do you synchronize father and son?

Comment: @alk I want to basically do this...   Modify the above program where parent read a message from the user and sends to the child
process. Child process sends the same message back to the server in capital form. Repeat this for ‘n’ messages.